# Upgrading my website to be multilangual, is this use of canonical code correct?

Tags: seo, redirects, html, multilingual

I have a good search-engine ranked webpage written in Dutch (=NL) and I have just upgraded my site to be in French too. So I've created subdirectories for NL and FR, but my root/index is now exactly the same as my /root/nl/index page… So I 302-redirect from my root/index to the correct subdir based on browser language. Is this the good way? (thinking about SEO and knowing my root/index has a good rating). But my biggest question is, how to handle the hreflang, canonical, maybe even x-default…

Here is my code:

```
MY FILENAME: root/index.html (= https://example.com/)

<html lang="nl-be">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/" /> 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
MY FILENAME: root/nl/index.html (= https://example.com/nl/)

<html lang="nl-be">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/" />
```

Is this correct? Should it be different?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite new to multi-lingual websites, but after reading [this article](http://www.htitipi.com/blog/tech-international.html), I would go like this:

#### `example.com/`:

- **if the content is the same at `example.com/` and at `example.com/nl/`**:

```html
<html lang="nl-BE">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/nl/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/">
```

- **if it is an international page**:

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/">
```

#### `example.com/nl/`:

```html
<html lang="nl-BE">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/nl/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/">
```

#### `example.com/fr/`:

```html
<html lang="fr-BE">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/fr/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://example.com/fr/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://example.com/nl/">
```

#### Also,

I would keep the `302 redirection` from `example.com/` to `example.com/nl/` or `example.com/fr/` based on the browser language.